# Build Skill for Echo Show

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I have build several skills for echo dot. Now, I am trying to build a skill for echo show. I have gone through several documentation:

- [Videoapp-interface-reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/videoapp-interface-reference)
- [Echo Show Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/best-practices-for-echo-show-skills)

But, I am not getting where to put the `directives` and how to use `lambda` for the same. None of the documentation tells us what to do with lambda function, what to put in `slots` and `utterances`. Can anyone tell me how to create a basis echo show skill to play video.

Here is a sample directive that I got from the documentation:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"sessionAttributes": null,
"response": {
    "outputSpeech": null,
    "card": null,
    "directives": [
     {
         "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
         "videoItem":
         {
             "source": "https://www.example.com/video/sample-video-1.mp4",
             "metadata": {
                 "title": "Title for Sample Video",
                 "subtitle": "Secondary Title for Sample Video"              
             }
         }
    }    
     ],
     "reprompt": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built a few skills for the echo show. Here's a sample json response that works. One thing to note and this is very important - DO NOT include the shouldEndSession attribute :)

```
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "response": {
        "reprompt": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "PlainText",
                "text": "Hello? Are you still there?"
            }
        },
        "outputSpeech": null,
        "card": null,
        "directives": [
            {
                "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
                "videoItem": {
                    "source": "[url to video.mp4]",
                    "metadata": {
                        "title": "Title meta",
                        "subtitle": "Secondary Title for Sample Video"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```